# How to access a global Javascript variable inside a ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

How to access a global Javascript variable inside a ng-grid ?

I have a global variable `var ShowApprovalLog = "True"` which I want to access inside the ng-grid cellTemplate.

```
{ 
  field: 'Urgent', 
  width:'60px',
  displayName: 'Urgent', 
  enableSorting: false,
  cellTemplate: 
      '<div class="ngSelectionCell">{{row.entity.Urgent}}
       <span ng-if=\"ShowApprovalLog ==\'True\' \">
       <img src=\"../Images/Urgent.png\" alt=\"Image\"/></span></div>'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put it in the $rootScope during the run section of your module?

```
angular.module('myModule', []).
config(function(injectables) { // provider-injector
  // This is an example of config block.
  // You can have as many of these as you want.
  // You can only inject Providers (not instances)
  // into config blocks.
}).
run(function(injectables) { // instance-injector
  // This is an example of a run block.
  // You can have as many of these as you want.
  // You can only inject instances (not Providers)
  // into run blocks
  $rootScope.ShowApprovalLog = "true"
});
```

You can access the value from any view with {{ShowApprovalLog}}